# Adding and Opening an DialogPage (or window) for MacOS (C#)

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm very new at programming in C# and Xamarin, and now I'm stuck.

I made a menu with some help, now I can do Cut/Copy/Paste which works fine, but now I want to make an Dialog or Window for some User Settings whenever they click on Settings in the menu. (I've made the menu in `AppDelegate.cs`)

I've look around a lot on Google and Xamarin forums, but al they talk about is to add a new kind of storyboard thingy. Which I guess will work, but I'm not using any storyboard (Just because we want to make everything out of code).

Found on Xamarin:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-dialogs/
And then the Preference window (That is what I prefer).

Code I made in AppDelegate.cs (Menu button which has to open an Window or Dialog):

```
var prefMenuItem = new NSMenuItem("Settings", ",", handler: delegate
    {
        var prefStyle = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

        var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
        prefWindow = new NSWindow(rect, prefStyle, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
        prefWindow.Title = "Settings";
        prefWindow.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
    });
```

*'Settings' Button in the menu is visible btw.*

Probably I forgot something, it won't open a thing.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you trying to create/open a Cocoa native window/dialog or a `Xamarin.Forms`-based Page from your MenuItem selection?

Comment: I don't know which one is better (For usage), because it needs to make it Possible to change some of the settings, like textcolor and the background (for example).

Comment: Are you trying to design your screens using `Xamarin.Forms` or directly using Cocoa native windows and controls (programmatically or via Storyboards)?

Comment: Programmaticly, because we don't use any storyboards

Comment: So, native Cocoa or Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Already found it, what Ronald Haan commented was what I needed. Still Thanks @SushiHangover .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
var prefMenuItem = new NSMenuItem("Settings", ",", handler: delegate
{
    var prefStyle = NSWindowStyle.Closable | NSWindowStyle.Resizable | NSWindowStyle.Titled;

    var rect = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(200, 1000, 1024, 768);
    prefWindow = new NSWindow(rect, prefStyle, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false);
    prefWindow.Title = "Settings";
    prefWindow.TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;

   NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(prefWindow);

});
```

I added `NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(prefWindow);` in your code. This will open a new window.

Found this on: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22729/xamarin-mac-how-to-set-position-of-modal-window

Comment: Thank you very much, at least now it will open a window :)