# Xamarin Forms for Mac runModalForWindow doesn't starting window as modal

Tags: cocoa, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms for Mac I have 2 windows:
A - main window
B - window that I want to open as modal.

Window B I opening using function RunModalForWindow.

Problem is that window B opening as common window and when I click on main window A the modal loses focus and goes out of the foreground.
How I can fix this problem?

Here is my code how I open my modal window:

```
this.window = new NSWindow(this.windowRect, NSWindowStyle.Closable, NSBackingStore.Buffered, false)
            {
                Title = "Pick install path",
                TitleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden,
            };
            
            PickInstallPath pickInstallPath = new();
            this.window.ContentViewController = pickInstallPath.CreateViewController();
            this.window.ContentViewController.PreferredContentSize = this.windowRect.Size;
            NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalForWindow(this.window);
```

Comment: You could try [Adding a Modal Window to a Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/user-interface/dialog#adding-a-modal-window-to-a-project).

Comment: Is there solution based on xaml forms without xcode?

Comment: You could look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46449607/10768653.

Comment: As you can see my code in example same as your link. So, I don't understand where is my problem.